# wpf move project sub folder to different location

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm

With MVVM the Images folder should be under Project folder or under View as a sub folder?

I originally have Images folder under Project folder with:

```
ImageBrush ImageSource="/DataTransfer;component/Images/image1.png"
```

and everything works fine.

Then I move the Images folder go under View folder and I specify:

```
ImageBrush ImageSource="/DataTransfer/View/Images/image1.png"
```

It throws:

```
at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)
at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
......
```

What do I need to do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
ImageBrush ImageSource="/DataTransfer;component/View/Images/image2.jpg"
```

But this question is not answered yet.

With MVVM the Images folder should be under Project folder or under View as a subfolder?